# getting a error: 'class WiFiServer' has no member named 'arg'

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

im getting a error like

```
error: 'class WiFiServer' has no member named 'arg'
```

my code

```
    #define ENA   14          // Enable/speed motors Right        GPIO14(D5)
    #define ENB   12          // Enable/speed motors Left         GPIO12(D6)
    #define IN_1  13          // L298N in1 motors Rightx          GPIO13(D7)
    #define IN_2  15          // L298N in2 motors Right           GPIO15(D8)
    #define IN_3  2           // L298N in3 motors Left            GPIO2(D4)
    #define IN_4  0           // L298N in4 motors Left            GPIO0(D3)
    
    #include "Arduino.h"
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiClient.h>
    #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
    #include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
    
    String command;             //String to store app command state.
    int speedCar = 100;         // 400 - 1023.
    
    const char* ssid = "your wifi";
    const char* password = "your password";
    
    WiFiServer server(80);
    
    IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 1, 184);
    
    IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
    
    IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 0, 0);
    
    void setup() {
     
     pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);  
     pinMode(IN_1, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(IN_2, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(IN_3, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(IN_4, OUTPUT); 
      
      Serial.begin(115200);
      
    // Connecting WiFi
    
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(500);
          Serial.print(".");
      }
    
      Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
      server.begin();
      Serial.println("Server Connected");
    
      Serial.print("Go to this link: https://");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }
    
    void goAhead(){ 
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_2,  HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goBack(){ 
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goRight(){ 
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goLeft(){
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goAheadRight(){
          
          digitalWrite(IN_1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
     
          digitalWrite(IN_3, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
       }
    
    void goAheadLeft(){
          
          digitalWrite(IN_1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, HIGH);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goBackRight(){ 
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void goBackLeft(){ 
    
          digitalWrite(IN_1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
      }
    
    void stopRobot(){  
          digitalWrite(IN_1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_2, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENA, speedCar);
    
          digitalWrite(IN_3, LOW);
          digitalWrite(IN_4, LOW);
          analogWrite(ENB, speedCar);
     }
    
    void loop() {
    
          WiFiClient client = server.available();
    
          if (!client) {
                return;
          }
    
          Serial.println("Waiting for new client");
    
          while (!client.available()) {
                delay(1);
          }
    
          String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
          Serial.println(request);
          client.flush();
    
          if (request.indexOf("/State=F")) command = "F";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=B")) command = "B";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=L")) command = "L";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=R")) command = "R";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=I")) command = "I";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=G")) command = "G";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=J")) command = "J";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=H")) command = "H";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=0")) command = "0";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=1")) command = "1";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=2")) command = "2";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=3")) command = "3";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=4")) command = "4";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=5")) command = "5";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=6")) command = "6";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=7")) command = "7";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=8")) command = "8";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=9")) command = "9";
          else if (request.indexOf("/State=S")) command = "S";
          else Serial.println("Wrong command");
        
          command = server.arg("State");
          if (command == "F") goAhead();
          else if (command == "B") goBack();
          else if (command == "L") goLeft();
          else if (command == "R") goRight();
          else if (command == "I") goAheadRight();
          else if (command == "G") goAheadLeft();
          else if (command == "J") goBackRight();
          else if (command == "H") goBackLeft();
          else if (command == "0") speedCar = 100;
          else if (command == "1") speedCar = 117;
          else if (command == "2") speedCar = 135;
          else if (command == "3") speedCar = 153;
          else if (command == "4") speedCar = 170;
          else if (command == "5") speedCar = 190;
          else if (command == "6") speedCar = 205;
          else if (command == "7") speedCar = 223;
          else if (command == "8") speedCar = 240;
          else if (command == "9") speedCar = 255;
          else if (command == "S") stopRobot();
    
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("");
    client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    client.println("<html>");
    client.println("<br><a href=\"/State=G\"><button>ahead left</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=F\"><button>ahead</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=I\"><button>ahead right</button></a><br>");
    client.println("<br><a href=\"/State=L\"><button>left</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=S\"><button>stop</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=R\"><button>right</button></a><br>");
    client.println("<br><a href=\"/State=H\"><button>back left</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=B\"><button>back</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=J\"><button>back right</button></a><br>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=0\"><button>Speed 0</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=1\"><button>Speed 1</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=2\"><button>Speed 2</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=3\"><button>Speed 3</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=4\"><button>Speed 4</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=5\"><button>Speed 5</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=6\"><button>Speed 6</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=7\"><button>Speed 7</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=8\"><button>Speed 8</button></a>");
    client.println("<a href=\"/State=9\"><button>Speed 9</button></a>");
    client.println("</html>");
    delay(1);
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");

}
```

actually im making a web controlled car where it can be controlled with any device.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You've confused `WiFiServer` for `ESP8266WebServer`.

`WiFiServer` simply listens for raw TCP connections and acts as a server for them. It is not and never has been a web server. TCP connections don't have arguments passed to them, so there is no `arg` method.

You need to rewrite your code to use `ESP8266WebServer` - you included the header file for it but never used it.

There are plenty of [examples on how to use it in its repository](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/examples).